# How can I allow the user to store multiple CSV files in a program from user input? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have this function active in my main program, at present it works great to save a single CSV file to the directory but I would like to allow the user to store and name multiple CSV files if needed. I have tried to initiate input for the file name but have received errors in doing so. Currently using the csv module.

````
def csvdata():
    while True:
        print("Press '1' to save student data to a CSV file, '2' to name and save a CSV file and '3' to return to the main menu.")
        answer = int(input("Enter your option: "))
        if answer == 1:
            with open('student.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(["Name","Grade"])
                writer.writerows(master_list)
                print("student.csv file saved")
        elif answer == 2:
            with open(input('Enter CSV file name:' '.csv', 'w', newline='')) as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(["Name", "Grade"])
                writer.writerows(master_list)
        elif answer == 3:
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid option")```
````

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? As in provide exactly what the use case is and what errors you are getting.

Comment: This line: `with open(input('Enter CSV file name:' '.csv', 'w', newline=''))` should be `with open(input('Enter CSV file name:') + '.csv', 'w', newline='')`. You are missing one parentheses after the call to `input` and you are not concatenating strings correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct:

```
with open(input('Enter CSV file name:' '.csv', 'w', newline='')) as f:
```

to

```
with open(input('Enter CSV file name:')+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
```